# 'ERROR 1031 (HY000): Table storage engine for ...' occured when creating index

Tags: mysql

Here is some querys. Database is gbase based on mysql.

```
gbase> show create table part;
+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        |
+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| part  | CREATE TABLE "part" (
      "P_PARTKEY" int(11) NOT NULL,
  "P_NAME" varchar(55) NOT NULL,
  "P_MFGR" char(25) NOT NULL,
  "P_BRAND" char(10) NOT NULL,
  "P_TYPE" varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  "P_SIZE" int(11) NOT NULL,
  "P_CONTAINER" char(10) NOT NULL,
  "P_RETAILPRICE" decimal(15,2) NOT NULL,
  "P_COMMENT" varchar(23) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=EXPRESS DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 TABLESPACE='sys_tablespace' |
+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (Elapsed: 00:00:00.01)

gbase> CREATE INDEX CASE2_INDEX_1 ON PART ( P_PARTKEY, P_SIZE );
ERROR 1031 (HY000): Table storage engine for 'part' doesn't have this option
```

I wanna create an index. But it dosen't work.

How can I register the index? Do you have any idea to solve?

Thanks for answering.

Comment: Never heard of the express engine before, but when the error message says, that this engine doesn't have this option, you will have to use another engine, when you desperately want an index. Simple as that.

Comment: I haven't experienced this database. And I don't know what other engines this database has.    But thanks your comment. I'm gonna try finding other.

Comment: When this is really MySQL you can choose from these: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/storage-engines.html The default is InnoDB, which should be fine, unless you have some really unusual requirements.

Comment: I just checked. I solved it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In gbase 8a express engine here is a example of index:

```sql
CREATE INDEX CASE2_INDEX_1 ON PART ( P_PARTKEY ) using hash global;
```

1. only one field can be used
2. add using hash global keyword as example above.